# Почему то не меняется header.php в wordpress и адаптивная верстка

Tags: wordpress, meta

Ставлю viewport и почему-то справа появляется пустое белое место на мобильных.
Это я ставил с помощью плагина, через фтп и через админку меняю, но всеравно он не хочет появляться

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1">
```

Сам header.php совсем не меняется, сначала пытался менять в ручную, но никаких изменений не вижу, но вроде как шаблоны и стили менять могу

сам сайт [сайт](http://ds-versal.ru)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это ни как не связано с `meta` тегами! У вас элемент списка (так называемого) со стрелкой `strelkaj`, имеет ширину 100% от ширины контейнера и еще отступ `padding: 10px 20px;`, т.е. получается 100% + 40px. Поэтому он и выступает из контейнера. Чтобы решить даную проблему можно использовать свойство `box-sizing` и задать значение `border-box`:

```
.row-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Инфо: http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing

Или если нужна поддержка IE 6-7, нужно обернуть элемент еще в один `div` и ему задать `width: 100%`. В вашем случаи можно как-то так сделать:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="strelkaj">
        <div class="span11 strelka">
            <a href="http://ds-versal.ru/uslugi/#dp">Дизайн-проект жилых, общественных и административных помещений </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: действительно, спасибо большое